# Taking Picture from camera gives small Image

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

If i want to take an image from Camera application,it is giving the small Image,If i access from gallery,it gives me enlarged image,Is there anyway to get the enlarged Image of camera .

Comment: Not directly. You can include a URI extra on the Intent, keyed with `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`, that specifies an output file for the full image, which you can then read from the disk.

Comment: In addition to @MikeM. answer, you can read more at http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath